# Как протестировать метод вывода в консоль java

Tags: java, консоль, testng

Как протестировать метод вывода в консоль?

```
String name = "Vasya";

public void printName() {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В классе `System` есть метод `setOut(PrintStream out)`, туда вы можете передать свою реализацию `PrintStream` и затем проверить, что было передано в качестве аргумента в тестируемый метод.

Но я рекомендую воспользоваться библиотекой для создания заглушек, например, [**mockito**](http://site.mockito.org/), чтобы не писать свою реализацию.

Тогда тестирование метода будет выглядеть так:

```
PrintStream stream = mock(PrintStream.class);
ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
System.setOut(stream);

String params = "hello world";
System.out.println(params);

verify(stream).println(captor.capture());
assertEquals(captor.getValue(), params);
```

Comment: Artem Konovalov А есть ли возможность при помощи mockito отслеживать сообщения выводящиеся на консоль ? Если не затруднит можете помочь с ответом на вопрос "Java как отследить сообщения выводящиеся на консоль"